# Injection of @Startup @Singleton bean instance is null - Tomee Webprofile 1.6.0.2

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-6

My instance of a @Singleton @Startup bean that Tomee is successfully creating, starting and placing in 'My Singleton Container' is null when I try to use it in a POJO. I've tried with and without the @ManagedBean anotation for the POJO.  Have I missed something basic in the spec or tutorial?

Many thanks in advance,
Ted S.

Tomee startup log:

```
Dec 21, 2014 2:48:24 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=MyStartupBean, ejb-name=MyStartupBean, container=My Singleton Container)
```

MyStartupBean.java:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MyStartupBean
{
    private final Properties _companyNames = new Properties();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() 
    {   
        _companyNames.put("key1", "ABC Company");
        _companyNames.put("key2", "XYZ Company");
     }

    public Properties getCompanyNames()
    {
        return _companyNames;
     }
}
```

MyPojo.java:

```
public class MyPojo
{
    @EJB
    private MyStartupBean _startupBean;
    private String _companyName;    

    public MyPojo(String inputKey)
    {
        Properties companyNames = _startupBean.getCompanyNames(); // <== _startupBean is null
        String name = companyNames.getProperty(inputKey);
        setCompanyName(name);
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String name)
    {
        _companyName = name;
    }

    public String getCompanyName()
    {
        return _companyName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably instantiating your pojo aren't you, e.g.

```
MyPojo mp = new MyPojo(someInput);
```

When you do that, injection doesn't work.  You need to use managed references to work with CDI/EJB components.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I understand how to use managed references when referring to the object with a web UI.  How are managed references used when the pojo is not being referenced by any browser UI?  i.e. The pojo is only instantiated when the system receives a message that is not initiated through a browser.  Thanks.

Comment: a message received - JMS or something else?

Comment: And I guess, how is the getter called?

Comment: Message is received through the SMS (text message) system. Getter is called on from another regularly instantiated pojo.

Comment: My original intent was to just declare an object in the application's main() method prior to and let the application refer to the object and not bother with annotations or CDI but I was unable to discover where they hide main() in this framework.

Comment: Why are you using an app server then?

Comment: I appreciate your responses.Many other interactions are through Web UIs. So it is a web application. I'll start another thread with the question "How can I instantiate an 'application' object that contains app initialization  data that pojos and managed objects can access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67437/discussion-between-john-ament-and-ted-spradley).